# Girl falls into tidal estuary / grey skinned people

Tags: story-identification

Trying to identify a book read somewhere in the late 70's / 80's. Can't remember much except that at one point a girl falls (maybe out of a plane?) into a warm river which she realizes is flowing inland and must therefore be an estuary. Also there was something about the inhabitants of this alien? Authoritarian? Militarised? State/world all having grey skin.